# Loop to do something n times without int i = 0?

Tags: c, pointers, for-loop

For a homework assignment, I am not allowed to use any variables like "int i = 0;" -- only pointers.

The problem is that I need to do something n times -- let's say 10 times -- but I can't figure out a way to do this said things n times without a for loop. It is manipulating a pointer to integer, and it is not terminated by zero, but the size is always the same (lets say 10).

Is there a way to do the following operation without using an integer to control the loop?

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    *(p + i) = 0;
}
```

Comment: Does the assignment say you have to use a loop? Because if not, you can simply do: `memset(p, 0, sizeof(int) * 10)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
int *q = p + 10;
while (p != q) {
    *p++ = 0;
}
```

UPDATE:

Doing this you would avoid using integers by just identifying a beginning (p) and an end (p + 10) and then just iterating over them.
It doesn't apply to this particular case but many times you don't know (or need to know) the size of an array.

Comment: While correct, it may not be wise to simply spoon-feed answers to people without at least explaining how your solution works.

Comment: @Insilico you're right, I tend to do that. Thanks for the observation. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
      #include <stdio.h>
      #include <stdlib.h>
      int main()
      {
        int *p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
        for(*p = 0; *p < 10; (*p)++)
             printf("%d\n", (*p));

      }
```